# How to install Nexus 6 / 5X / 6P Drivers in Windows 7 properly where fastboot can see it?

Tags: rooting, adb, fastboot, bootloader-lock, nexus-5x

I have the Nexus 5X drivers installed properly on Win7 64bit and it shows up in my device manager as Nexus 5x. I can verify that it gets detected as I see it in chrome inspect page. But when i try to do a adb devices or fastboot devices, it wont see the phone. what could i be doing wrong?

And yes I can transfer files when I select MTP mode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADB devices was detecting the phone, but fastboot devices wasn't. I had to do the following to get it to work on Win 7 64bit:

- Reboot Win7 and Press F8 on boot screen and select: **Disable Driver Signing**
- Boot phone into bootloader
- Device Manager you should see an **Unknown Device** popup
- Manually install the driver by selecting: android > android adb (screenshot)
- Then goto command line: fastboot devices

Let me know if it worked or not. If it did, all I ask is thumbs up this post! I spent a good 3 hours to figure it out. No where on the net has a solution that I've found.

[image]